# problems compiling openni2_camera : package 'OpenNI2' not found

Tags: ros, openni2-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I am new to ROS, So kindly forgive me if this problem is too trivial.

I am trying to interface an Occipital Structure sensor with ROS. I followed a couple of tutorials few among which is
http://eras.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servers/body_tracker/doc/setup.html

https://dobots.nl/2014/05/05/asus-xtion-using-openni2-and-ros-on-udoo/

http://forums.structure.io/t/how-to-ros-odroid/1722

I have the Opnenni2 working and the sensor working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Now I am trying to make the openni2_camera, opnnni2_launch and rgbd_launch in my catkin workspace, but the make fails as its not finding the library libopenni2  or module openni2.

Console o/p:

-- checking for module 'libopenni2'

--   package 'libopenni2' not found

-- checking for module 'OpenNI2'

--   package 'OpenNI2' not found

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
A required package was not found

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
openni2_camera/CMakeLists.txt:13 (pkg_check_modules)

I read in the cmake documentation that CMake first check libraries in the ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} so I have also added the path where my libopenni2.so resides. "shown below"

akshay@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ echo $CMAKE_MODULE_PATH

/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenNI2/Bin/x86-Release:

But the compilation still fails. I’m not sure, how to add the path of the library so that the dependencies are fulfilled.

Kindly HElp!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209223/problems-compiling-openni2_camera-:--package-%27openni2%27-not-found/) by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, I tried include_directories to include the path where openni2 was built, but didn't work. I tried "sudo  apt-get install ros-indigo-openni2-launch" as suggested in a few discussions, and it worked. It also installed the required dependencies so, i was able to get my occipital sensor working.

---

Originally posted by [SpacemanSPIFF](https://answers.ros.org/users/22434/spacemanspiff/) with karma: 78 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have some modifications to make to your cMakeLists.txt, like in the find_package or include_directories; or to your package.xml.
You should find some help in the followings tutorials :
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29

---

Originally posted by [Swan Baigne](https://answers.ros.org/users/21982/swan-baigne/) with karma: 47 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1